# Error on delete function cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an issue with the cascade deletion, I'm using the default delete function and added the parameter true to allow cascade deletion so if I run:

```
$this->Users->delete($user,true);
```

I get a fatal error:

> Unsupported operand types in
>   /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php
>   on line 1628

And if I run it without the true parameter for cascade deletion:

```
$this->Users->delete($user);
```

I get the an error because of the foreign keys:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`real_estate`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_users10` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Do you have the proper model relationships like described in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add a option for a cascading delete, and as burzum said you are passing a string as an array.

When deleting entities, associated data can also be deleted. If your HasOne and HasMany associations are configured as dependent, delete operations will ‘cascade’ to those entities as well

```
// In a Table's initialize method.
$this->hasMany('Comments', [
    'dependent' => true,
]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#cascading-deletes

Answer (score 1):

The first error already tells you what is wrong.

> Unsupported operand types

Pretty clear? No? [Check the API](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_delete).

```
delete( Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity , array|ArrayAccess $options [] )
```

It's accepting only an array as 2nd arg.

The 2nd error is a plain SQL error, either remove the constraint from the DB or fulfil it. If I read this right you'll have to pass the user_id besides the id in the entity you're passing to delete.